# USB 3.0 stick inhibits USB mouse

Tags: 16.04, usb, mouse, usb-drive

I have a keyboard/mouse `Logitech Wireless Desktop MK270` that works very well. I recently bought this [USB stick](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B01BGTG3JA/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00). When I plug it in, the mouse is inhibited: the cursor disappears completely. When I unplug the key, everything goes back to normal. The stick is not mounted automatically when plugged in.

I run Ubuntu 16.04. Here is the output of `lsusb` with the stick plugged in:

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0781:5583 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I tried to plugging the stick and keyboard/mouse receiver into different ports, but it's the same.

I tested the stick on other computers:

- Raspberry Pi 3B without keyboard/mouse: the stick is mounted automatically read/write, but it's unwritable.
- Old computer 16.04 with USB2.0 and wired keyboard/mouse: works as expected. I copied 45GB of videos on it without problem.
- DVD/BlueRay reader: the stick works as expected.

So it seems to be a sort of incompatibility between the stick and the USB receiver.

Comment: some bios has certain configuration about usb 3.0 port, especially in some new motherboard. could you check it?

Comment: I have a Asrock deskmini 110 computer. I saw some settings in the BIOS about UEFI and XHCI, both disabled. The stick was formatted as FAT32, I reformatted it as NTFS, now it is mounted automatically, but the mouse problem is the same.

Comment: if xhci disabled, usb 3.0 port will operate in 2.0 standard ehci mode. And uefi has nothing to do about your problem. So, try to enabled xhci mode in your bios.

Comment: Thnks, good to know. I enabled XHCI, but the problem is the same. I made further tests and edited my question.

Comment: I agree that it seems to be a sort of incompatibility between the stick and the USB system. You have bad luck: this is unusual. I guess it depends on the interaction between driver and the hardware, and the driver comes with the kernel. So you might have better luck with another version of Ubuntu (to get another kernel series), newer or older. You can download several iso files and try them live before installing. You can even try the developing version, 'Artful' (to become 17.10 in October), if you are prepared for some adventures, http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/376/builds

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure to be ready for such adventure ! I will use the stick on my old big slow computer and forget it for my new tiny fast one...

Comment: I do search some thread, it seems your usb wireless interfere the frequency of 3.0 usb devices. See [this](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/io/universal-serial-bus/usb3-frequency-interference-paper.html) and [this one](http://support.logitech.com/en_gb/article/38032) has good explanation. According to those article, the possible solution is extending your usb port using usb extension cable (adjust to some range where there is not produce any frequency interfere any more.)

Comment: Many thanks @adadion, it works! I think you should make your comment an answer, it could be useful for other users.

Comment: Glad that it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [this](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/io/universal-serial-bus/usb3-frequency-interference-paper.html) and [this good explanation](http://support.logitech.com/en_gb/article/38032), there is possibility of frequency interfere caused 3.0 usb devices that affecting any of wireless mouse and keyboard.

So the possible solution is extending your usb port using usb extension cable (adjust to some range where there is not produce any frequency interfere any more. ***Tips**: place the receiver as close as possible to the wireless device)

Comment: that seems unlikely as the cursor would not completely vanish because of RFI.

Comment: @Wug I'm afraid it does. See on OP's comment on his post :)

Comment: It might also be the case that the USB extension kit (cable or cable + adapter) is recognized correctly and activates a driver, that works well with the two conflicting USB devices. Anyway, you found a solution :-)

Comment: The receiver was plugged behind the central unit, the stick front. I simply plugged the receiver to a standard USB cable extension, then put the receiver very near my mouse/keyboard. It works like a charm.

Comment: Not having a good connection shouldn't cause the cursor to disappear. I've seen interference before and I can't fathom why a poor signal would cause the OS to stop drawing the mouse cursor, something it continues to do even with no mouse connected at all.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes have to use a Lenovo Ideapad 320 if I need to work from home. I have Ubuntu MATE 18.04 on a USB stick plugged into either of the only two available USB3 ports (no USB 2.0 port) on the left side of the laptop. When the USB stick is busy reading/writing files, my wireless mouse whose dnngle is plugged in beside it behaves erratically.

Searching further, I learned about the interference and the possible mitigation. Sadly, I do not have a USB extension cord neither another USB port on the right side of the laptop.

What I did was wrap the entire body of the USB with a piece of foil. The reflective surface should be on the outside. That did the trick for me.

[image: USB3 stick w/ foil]